# Understanding How a Method Calculates a Number Raised to a Power

Tags: java, exponent

I came across a class that solves an exponent problem but I couldn't wrap my head around how the method `raiseToPower()` works. This is the line that I don't understand: `resultVal = baseVal * raiseToPower(baseVal,exponentVal-1);`

What is `baseVal` being multiplied by? `raiseToPower(baseVal,exponentVal-1)` doesn't seem like an expression to me. If `baseVal == 2`, than what is `raiseToPower(baseVal,exponentVal-1)`?

I know how to solve 2^3 in my head, I struggle to understand the steps `baseVal * raiseToPower(baseVal,exponentVal-1)` takes to solve the problem. I know that `exponentVal` is decremented by 1 each time `raiseToPower()` is invoked, but I still don't understand how it's holding a value that can be multiplied by `baseVal`.

I understand that this recursive method behaves like a loop.

```
public class ExponentMethod {
    
   // calculates the result of raising a number to a power
   public static int raiseToPower(int baseVal, int exponentVal) {
      
      int resultVal;    // holds the answer to the exponent problem

      // sets resultVal to 1
      if (exponentVal == 0) {
         resultVal = 1;
      }

      else {
          
          // calculate math problem
         resultVal = baseVal * raiseToPower(baseVal,exponentVal-1);
      }

      // returns when exponentVal == 0
      return resultVal;
   }
   
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      int userBase;
      int userExponent;

      userBase = 2;
      userExponent = 3;
      System.out.println(userBase + "^" + userExponent + " = "
        + raiseToPower(userBase, userExponent));
   }
}

// output
2^3 = 8
```

I am aware that a pow() method exists for raising a number to a power

Thanks,

Comment: This means if you are given to 2^3 , it can also be written as 2*2^2 . Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is using recursion to raise a specific base to a certain power.

Let us take a simple example of 2^2 and run through the code:

`raiseToPower(2, 2)` is called

`resultVal = 2 * raiseToPower(2, 2 - 1)` is run

`raiseToPower(2, 1)` is called

`resultVal = 2 * raiseToPower(2, 1 - 1)` is run

`raiseToPower(2, 0)` is called

Base case is hit and we return `1`

Now we go back up the chain!

`resultVal = 2 * 1` and 2 is returned

`resultVal = 2 * 2` and 4 is returned

So the end result for 2^2 is 4 as expected.

Another way to think about this is suppose someone already gave you the answer to 2^2, can you use that to calculate 2^3? Yes, you can simply do 2 * 2^2!

So: `raisePower(2,3) = 2 * raisePower(2,2)`

It is important to also have a base case (when power is 0, like in your example above) so that we don't run into an infinite loop! Hope this helps.

Comment: When `baseVal == 0` we returned 1. Tha much is clear but going up the chain is unclear to me.

Comment: Does trying it out on smaller powers help you visualise it better? like `raisePower(2,1) = 2 * raisePower(2,0)` and you already know `raisePower(2,0)` returns 1

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is that this is a recursive method which calls itself.  It continues to do so, storing intermediate results on the call stack until it starts to return, popping those values from the stack to form the answer.  Sometimes, a print statement within the method can help you see what is happening.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(raiseToPower(3,4));  
}
    
public static int raiseToPower(int baseVal, int exponentVal) {
    if (exponentVal == 0) {
       return 1;
    }
    int x = baseVal * raiseToPower(baseVal, exponentVal-1); 
    System.out.println("exponentVal = " + exponentVal + ",  + x = " + x);
    return x;
}
```

prints

```
exponentVal = 1,  + x = 3
exponentVal = 2,  + x = 9
exponentVal = 3,  + x = 27
exponentVal = 4,  + x = 81
81
```

As the recursive call unwinds when the exponentVal == 0, here is what you get

```
x = 1;
x = x * baseVal; // x = baseVal
x = x * baseVal; // x = baseVal ^ 2
x = x * baseVal; // x = baseVal ^ 3
x = x * baseVal; // x = baseVal ^ 4
// return x or 81
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets take example and understand :

baseValue = 2;
exponentialValue = 3;

How we can calculate pow(2,3) , there are ways of that :

1. baseValue^exponentialValue ---- 2^3 = 8
2. baseValue x baseValue^exponentialValue-1 ---- 2x2^2 = 8

Answer (score 1):

It's called recursion. The same function is being called recursively with the exponent decreasing each time, multiplied with the base value and added into result. It would run like so:

[image: Recursive calls]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when solving this problem. The direct fix for the "// calculate math problem" line is:

```
resultVal = baseVal * raiseToPower(baseVal, (exponentVal-1));
```